# Complex Eigenvalues of a Certain Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonnegative-matrices

Suppose that M is an $n\times n$ upper triangular matrix, with 1's on the diagonal, for which $-1\leq m_{ij}\leq 0$ for all $i<j$. Let N be the matrix $M^{-1}M^T$. Prove that the complex eigenvalues of N have absolute value 1.

I have shown this for $n\leq 4$. In general, the lower bound on $m_{ij}$ cannot be dropped completely, as I have found an 8 x 8 counterexample in which one of the $m_{ij}$ is -5 and the others 0 or -1. However, extensive attempts with Mathematica to contradict the stated conjecture have proved unsuccessful.

This problem has a long history and is related to Coxeter groups. For instance, R.Howlett (Bull.London Math.Soc. 14 (1982), 137-141) gives a simple argument that it is true if $M+M^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: So your problem is to prove that all the eigenvalues of $N$ come in reciprocal pairs??

Comment: No, that is not the same thing. I. claim that $1/\lambda=\overline\lambda$ when $\lambda$ is not a real eigenvalue.

Comment: For instance, in my $8 x 8$ counterexample, there are six complex eigenvalues, including $9.20444+1.75272 i$ and its reciprocal $0.104842-0.019964 i$, which are not of absolute value 1. There is also the eigenvalues $-0.865766+0.500449 i$ and its reciprocal, which are indeed of absolute value 1.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand your problem better now. So your claim is, $$\forall \lambda \in \sigma(N) \backslash \mathbb{R}, |\lambda| = 1  $$?

Comment: Yes. As Howlett says, suppose that $M^{-1}M^Tv=\lambda v$. Then $\overline {v} M^T v=\lambda \overline{v} M v$. Conjugating, we have $\overline{v} Mv=\overline{\lambda}\overline{v}  M^Tv=\overline{\lambda}\lambda \overline{v}Mv$. Therefore either $\overline{\lambda}\lambda=1$, or $\overline{v} M v=0$ and $\overline{v} M^T v=0$ as well. It follows that $\overline{v}(M+M^T)v=0$ and so $v=0$ if $M+M^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: When n=4 and

\begin{equation}
M=
\begin{matrix}
1&-a&-b&-c\\
0&1&-d&-e\\
0&0&1&-f\\
0&0&0&1
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

$Det(xM-M^T)=x^2(y^2+(r-4)y+(t^2-2r+4))$, where $y=x+1/x$, $r=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2+h$, $h=abd+ace+bcf+def+acdf$ and $t=cd-be+af$. The quadratic in y has real roots if  $r^2-4t^2\geq 0$. The corresponding values of x are either a pair of reciprocal real roots, or a pair of conjugate complex roots of absolute value 1.
Now $r-2t=(c-d)^2+(a-f)^2+(b+e)^2+h$ and $r+2t=(c+d)^2+(a+f)^2+(b-e)^2+h$, both of which are $\geq 0$ by the hypothesis, so $r^2-4t^2\geq 0$.